# Transpose by grouping a Dataframe having both numeric and string variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame and I want to convert it into the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[111,111,111,222,222,333],
                   'class':['merc','humvee','bmw','vw','bmw','merc'],
                   'imp':[1,2,3,1,2,1]})
print(df)
    ID   class  imp
0  111    merc    1
1  111  humvee    2
2  111     bmw    3
3  222      vw    1
4  222     bmw    2
5  333    merc    1
```

**Desired output:**

```
    ID       0        1       2
0  111    merc   humvee     bmw
1  111       1        2       3
2  222      vw      bmw
3  222       1        2
4  333    merc      
5  333       1
```

I wish to `transpose` the entire dataframe, but `grouped by` a particular column, `ID` in this case and maintaining the row `order`.

**My attempt:** I tried using `.set_index(`) und `.unstack()`, but it did not work.

Comment: Does the column names in the output has any significance or it can be anything?

Comment: It can be anything ....01,,2 or col1,col2,col3 ..... but maintaining  a particular order....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter and then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['ID',df.groupby('ID').cumcount()])
         .stack()
         .unstack(1, fill_value='')
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
    ID     0       1    2
0  111  merc  humvee  bmw
1  111     1       2    3
2  222    vw     bmw     
3  222     1       2     
4  333  merc             
5  333     1
```

Comment: Thanks Josef for the answer. Just a small question before I accept it. Will the order of the columns ´class´ and ´imp´ be maintained in the rows? I mean, for every group, the value appearing forst in the dataframe will appear first in the rows as well? Like 0,1,2 and never 2,0,1?

Comment: @cph_sto - No, it is sorting by alphanumeric. So for 100 % sure correct ordering need rename columns, give me some time for solution.

Comment: Oh I see. Actually, if merc is appearing on the top followed by humvee and bmy, then same order must be followed ..... Thanks for your help.

Comment: @cph_sto - Not sure if understand, just tested with `pd.DataFrame({'ID':[111,111,111,222,222,333],
                   'z':['merc','humvee','bmw','vw','bmw','merc'],
                   'a':[1,2,3,1,2,1]})` and `pd.DataFrame({'ID':[111,111,111,222,222,333],
                   'a':['merc','humvee','bmw','vw','bmw','merc'],
                   'z':[1,2,3,1,2,1]})` and got same output, so in last pandas versions (tested in pandas 1.1.3) it working same and correct.

Comment: What I meant is that, if in the initial `df` for `ID` 111, row 0,1,2 are merc, humvee & bmw respectively. Now, when we transpose, all I want it to ensure that column 0,1,2 are merc, humvee and them bmw and not merc, bmw and then humvee. The order from the initial dataframe must be maintained when transposed.

Comment: @cph_sto - For data reshaping is used counter by `cumcount` for new columns names. So this order is used for new columns names, here `0,1,2`. So I think it not change ordering from original order in `df.class`, `df.imp`.

Answer (score 2):

Another method would be to use `groupby` and `concat` - although this is not totally dynamic it works fine if you only have two columns you want to work with, namely `class` and `imp`

```
s = df.set_index([df['ID'],df.groupby('ID').cumcount()]).unstack(1)

df1 = pd.concat([s['class'],s['imp']],axis=0).sort_index().fillna('')

print(df1)

idx     0       1    2
ID                    
111  merc  humvee  bmw
111     1       2    3
222    vw     bmw     
222     1       2     
333  merc             
333     1
```